# fetch request not working with headers

Tags: reactjs, web-services, spring-boot, fetch

I am working on login page with ReactJs,Spring Boot and rest web services.My Reactjs frontend application is running on port 8080 while my webservice/spring boot application is running on port 9090. I am trying to use the "fetch" method to connect with my backend code, but I am facing error while passing headers in fetch request. If I remove headers property, execution goes into the called backend method. I need to pass Headers in fetch method as it required to access them in web service method.

Please find Snapshot of network requests and responses. [Without Headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9lmHc.png) [With headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GT3i0.png)

Below is my code of React JSX file:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
class App extends Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state={
            email:'',
            password:''
        }
        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
   }

    handleClick(){

       var usernameFieldValue = this.refs.emailField.value;
       var passwordFieldValue = this.refs.passwordField.value;
       this.setState({email:usernameFieldValue})
       this.setState({password:passwordFieldValue})

       //var headers = 'Basic bmltZXNoLnBhdGVsQHRhdHZhc29mdC5jb206cGFzc3dvcmQ=';
       //alert(headers);
        fetch('http://192.168.0.239:9090/ws/login',{
            mode: 'cors',
            method: 'get',
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                "Authorization": "Basic bmltZXNoLnBhdGVsQHRhdHZhc29mdC5jb206cGFzc3dvcmQ="    
            }
        }).then((response) => response.json())
        .then((responseJson) => {
           alert(" responseJson : " + responseJson);
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            alert("Error : " +error);
          });
    }    

    render() {
      return (
              <div id="loginFrame">
                  <div className="container">
                      <div id="loginHeader" className="row">
                          <div className="col-xs-12 text-center">
                              <img src="" alt="'Logo" />
                          </div>
                      </div>
                      <div id="loginBody" className="row">
                      <div className="col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-3">
                          <div className="center-block">
                              <div id="login-panel">
                                  <form id="loginForm" className="form-horizontal" role="form">
                                      <div className="form-group">
                                          <input type="text" className="form-control input-lg" id="email" name="email" ref="emailField" placeholder="Email address"/>
                                      </div>
                                      <div className="form-group">
                                          <input type="password" className="form-control input-lg" id="password" name="password" ref="passwordField" placeholder="Password"/>
                                      </div>
                                      <div className="form-group">
                                          <button onClick={this.handleClick} className="btn btn-lg btn-success pull-right">Login</button>
                                      </div>
                                  </form>
                              </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
      );
   }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: What's the error ?

Comment: If I am including the header, fetch call is not working. and if I am not using headers It is throwing me "Error : TypeError: Failed to fetch" error. @Umesh

Comment: `method` should be `GET` not `get` I guess.

Comment: I changed it with 'GET'. Still facing same issue.

Comment: Fetch requires a Headers object, e.g. var h = new Headers(). See MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

Comment: I have also tried that @dannyjolie

Comment: I'm really confused.... your "Without headers" screenshot shows the request failing (presumably client side because the status is "canceled"), but the "With headers" screenshot is working, albeit without the actual headers you included in the request. Can you clarify exactly what's going on? Are the screenshot labels flipped? Also check the Javascript console for errors too.

Comment: @Dhaval, can you check your backend api is working fine .e.g like using postman etc

Comment: @Umesh Yes I have checked it with Postman. I am getting appropriate response in that. So backend api is working properly.

Comment: @ccnokes The screenshots labels are proper. I am getting this error in console while using headers :


 "Fetch API cannot load http://192.168.0.239:9090/ws/login. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed access. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled."

Comment: I also tried this trick and Now I am able to fire request with header successfully but it is browser specific configuration for development. I need it for production environment. 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3102819/disable-same-origin-policy-in-chrome

Answer (score 1):

```
var url = "https://yourUrl";
    var bearer = 'Bearer '+ bearer_token;
    fetch(url, {
    method: 'GET',
    withCredentials: true,
    credentials: 'include',
    headers: {
        'Authorization': bearer,
        'X-FP-API-KEY': 'iphone',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
    }).then((responseJson) => {
        var items = JSON.parse(responseJson._bodyInit);
    })
    .catch(error => this.setState({
    isLoading: false,
    message: 'Something bad happened ' + error
    }));
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `mode: cors`, this is default.

```
const headers = new Headers({
  "Content-Type": "application/json",
  "Authorization": "Basic bmltZXNoLnBhdGVsQHRhdHZhc29mdC5jb206cGFzc3dvcmQ="  
});

fetch('http://192.168.0.239:9090/ws/login', {
  method: 'GET',
  headers,
}).then().then().catch();
```

Comment: It's still not working. I have already checked with removing "mode:cors" option. Fetch is not working if I include Headers in my fetch method. @Dan

Comment: Can you see the network request in your dev tools? Any console errors?

Comment: I have added snapshots of network request and responses both cases (with and without headers)

Comment: With header included it showing me Ok with code 200 but in real the request is not fired in backend side. It will directly catch by "Error" method below the fetch method.

Comment: The problem might not necessarily be related to fetch as you are successfully making a HTTP GET request. Your backend might be the problem.

Comment: In debug mode, with headers included in fetch, the execution is not at all going to backend while the execution is going to backend without headers. The same backend method is working fine while using Angular js as front end.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments, it sounds like the underlying problem is that you're doing a CORS request from your react app, which is being served from a different server than your spring backend. I don't know Spring, but adding a `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` HTTP header (as well as some other CORS related headers) will clear up the problem. I'm not 100% sure why when you fetch with no headers, it works. There may be a deeper configuration issue or you need to configure it to allow requests with those headers you're passing (`Access-Control-Allow-Headers`). Note that if you don't plan to allow cross-origin requests in production you may want to add those headers except when in development.

You can also fetch in no CORS mode (pass `{mode: 'no-cors'}`), but there's a lot of limitations to that and I doubt that's what you want.